# c# winforms, состояние строки Connection string

Tags: c#

пишу десктоп приложение на C# winform с базой данных Mysql, (сервер Wampserver), я указал IP адрес ПК на котором стоит сервер, но IP адрес ПК постоянно меняется(IP адрес автоматом назначается wi-fi  роутером), мне постоянно приходится заново задавать IP на всех формах где есть поле Connection string , как можно избавиться от этого, чтобы IP адрес автоматом назначался в Connection string ? у меня приложение установлен на 6 ПК,они через wi-fi роутер по Локальке соединяется, собирают данные.

```
 DataTable dt = new DataTable("ssa");
    MySqlCommand command;
    MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection("server = 192.168.1.119; UserId = superadmin; Password = super; database = baza");
    MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter();
    int ID;
```

Comment: Для этого делается статический адрес, чтоб ваш роутер выдавал под ваш мак только конкретный адрес. Делается это либо в настройках подключения на компьютере (указывается нужный IP), либо в настройках роутера ищется DHCP-сервер, у которого и задается mac и ip. Если вам нужно прям чтоб автоматически, то сканируйте всю сеть на наличие открытого порта, а потом пытайтесь подключиться, но это изврат... И да, если приложение должно работать за пределами вашей сети, то выделенный ip покупается у провайдера!

Comment: если я захочу подключит ПК  по физически соединённой сети, допустим у меня 3 флиала между собой подключенный по Оптической кабели , между ними проходит ПИНГ , я все равно должен буду приобрести Белый IP ?  вообще нормально что я пользуюсь бесплатным Wampserver-ов для такого проекта ? дайте пожалуйста советы

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сервера на предприятиях делают со статическими адресами. Привыкайте к корпоративным стандартам, способы работы с динамическими IP-адресами есть, но очень геморроные, не стоит костыли ставить там, где вы всё равно со временем поймёте, что корпоративные практики часто очень хороши.

Ситуация про "в трёх филиалах" это означает, что сисадмины настроили маршрутизацию между филиалами и сервера видят друг друга, это не совсем о том, но всё же: внутри филиалов никто не ставит динамические IP для серверного оборудования.

Условно, филиал А имеет IP вида 10.1.x.y, филиал Б - 10.1.x.y, филиал Ц — 10.3.x.y — а как их админы пробрасывают это могут быть разные способы. В принципе, для этого даже не особо обязательно, чтобы узел выхода в интернет имел постоянный IP, хотя как правило у провайдеров его всё же обычно прибивают гвоздями.

И внутри каждого филиала есть подсетки для рабочих станций сотрудников, где IP раздаются через DHCP, а есть подсети с серверами, где IP у каждого сервера фиксированное.

> IP адрес автоматом назначался в Connection string

В эту сторону даже не смотрите, это никогда вам на производстве не пригодится: лучше прокачивайте свои навыки программиста в тех вещах, которые реально нужны и важны.

На текущий момент вам достаточно зайти на свой Wi-Fi адаптер и прописать фиксированный IP для MAC-адреса своей машины. Либо открыть свойства подключения и вбить постоянный IP-адрес, в простейшем случае — текущий.

У меня например, дома есть роутер и есть схема сети (Network Planning Guide), написанный мной для себя, в которой описано, что домашние машины имеют динамические IP в диапазоне от 192.168.1.200 до .250, сервера (у меня много виртуальных машин) имеют статические адреса 192.168.1.100 - 199. Ну и сам роутер мнит себя как 192.168.1.1 - шлюз по умолчанию.

Comment: А К , спасибо большое за подробный разбор !  буду настраивать роутер